# Como Puedo enviar data en una api usando HTTPclient content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, api

Estoy haciendo una función para consumir una api sin embargo no sé como enviar la data del body como HTTPclient content type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded ya que como lo hago actualmente lo envía como raw, este es el código que he armado:

```
 public static object GetDataToken(HttpClient client)
        {
            try
            {
                IniFile seccionLOG = new IniFile(@"C:/TTLKN/LFE/SETTINGS/SettingsEnviaRC.ini", "API");
                string apiBase = "https://api.com/cloud/devl";
                ConsumeToken data = new ConsumeToken();
                data.client_id = seccionLOG.Read("CLIENT_ID");
                data.grant_type = "password";
                data.username = seccionLOG.Read("API_USER");
                data.password = seccionLOG.Read("API_PASS");
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(apiBase, stringContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                var responseContent = response.Content;
                var content = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                dynamic respuesta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
                return respuesta;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
                return false; 
            }
```

Si alguien sabe como hacerlo ya que no he encontrado solución alguna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dict.Add("client_id", seccionLOG.Read("CLIENT_ID"));
dict.Add("grant_type", "password");
dict.Add("username", seccionLOG.Read("API_USER"));
dict.Add("password", seccionLOG.Read("API_PASS"));

var client = new HttpClient();
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiBase) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
var res = client.SendAsync(req).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Y hay forma de hacer esto mismo pero de manera sincrona? ya que si aplico esto tendré que cambiar todo a asincrono y eso va a modificar mucho mi código

Comment: Claro, sería agregarle estos metodos a `SendAsync`, .`GetAwaiter().GetResult();` lo que quedaría de la siguiente forma: `var res = client.SendAsync(req).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado, me salvaste la existencia jaja